# Amazon Product Advertising API ItemSearch Signature Error in Php

Tags: php, web-services, amazon-web-services

I tried ItemLookup like this,

```
http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[AccessId]&AssociateTag=[AssociateId]&IdType=ISBN&ItemId=8129135728&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes%2CImages&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-05-12T13%3A42%3A02Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=[Signature]
```

It is working fine for me.

I tried this for ItemSearch,

```
http://webservices.amazon.in/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=[AccessId]&AssociateTag=[AssociateId]&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Small&SearchIndex=All&Keywords=harry_potter&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2015-05-12T13%3A39%3A22Z&Version=2011-08-01&Signature=[Signature]
```

But,it is not working and showing Signature doesn't match error.

Can anybody help me in correcting ItemSearch Request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have started with the following as it looks similar to the URL that you have created

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/SubmittingYourFirstRequest.html

Double check the timestamp as the page mentions it can't be more than 15 minutes old

But I'm afraid I don't know that API well enough to know how to get the signature setup correctly but have you considered using a library

[This seems like a nice example](http://apaiio.dev.pixel-web.org/) of what can be achieved with the library http://exeu.github.io/apai-io/

Comment: @Cartton Thank you.It helped me to find the mistake in my request.The problem is with Keywords string.

Comment: I found the correct request here, http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html